# Generating unique strings for email activation links PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

My question is a bit tricky and couldn’t find the right manner in which to efficiently articulate it.
I’m creating a unique activation string/link that combines a hashed username and time in PHP.
However the exact time it gets the data to be sent to my database and the actual time it takes to send the email activation link  to the user’s email account is different (maybe in milliseconds and sometimes seconds)-and this basically means I have different email activation Links from my database and email account.
Let me show a code snippet:

```
$username = $_POST[‘username’];
$table = ‘users’;
$activate_field = ‘activate’;
$activate_code = md5($_POST[‘username’]) +  time(); //provides unique code for activating
//few more lines of code then…
$query = $connect-> prepare(“INSERT INTO $table $acivate_field VALUES $activate_code”);
$query->execute();

//then the long code for sending the email with the activation code appended to the user’s email account
```

Is there a better way of generating unique strings every second maybe?
Thanks for your time and appreciate any help and/or suggestions.P.S I'm using phpmailer for sending emails.

Comment: You can simply take the unique field (for example the email or the username) and `md5` it. It will be unique in this context.

Comment: it's normal that  the times are different, you just have to use one time for both operations. as you save the information in the database, that's a more costly operation. You have to use this time to send links and for the other operation needed.

Comment: Well the value for `$activate_code ` should only be evaluated once, so there is no reason they should be different. also `time` is already in seconds. Are you sure that something in the `//few more lines of code then...` section isn't modifying the `$activate_code`?

Comment: Also, you're trying to concatenate a string (`md5()` returns a string) with an int (return value of `time()`) by using the arithmetic addition operator (`+`). Since `md5` does not return a value that's directly parsed to an int by php the result will be interpreted as 0 and you're losing your md5-part of your ID currently. (Example fiddle: [Link](http://codepad.org/Qwk0QggT))

Comment: thanks for the help and suggestions, @Andrew that answer is probably what I'll Implement and thanks for the valuable points you making guys-will consider them in the future.

Comment: @ccKep will maybe wrapping both time and username in md5 help?

Comment: well hashing both the email and unique id works fine, tiil you manually deactivate the user-they still posses the ability to re-activate their account via that unique previous string u sent.

Answer (score 2):

simply write generated code to variable and then variable to mail and database
as I can see you already have code kept in variable before including it in your query

on a side note, you shouldn't access superglobals like $_POST directly as user input may be malicious
and for the same reason you should use PDO prepared statements instead of string built queries

Comment: The only place I see $_POST being used, it's being `md5`'d, which will result in a SQL-safe string. As long as `$username` doesn't get put directly into a SQL query later on, this looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

[`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) in mysql is better however [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) in php with a prefix can be good as well.

Comment: PHPs uniqid is already based on microtime, there's no need to prefix it with microtime aswell. The prefix is only needed if you're generating IDs across multiple hosts (to still ensure uniqueness you'd tell every host to use a different prefix)

Answer (score 1):

You can [`md5`](http://php.net/md5),  with the combination of [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and [`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) so it will also unique on same second.

```
$activate_code = md5(uniqid(time()));
```